# Shopify sales channel (App bridge not using properly issue)

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app

i developed a shopify sales channel in PHP and it embbeded inside shopify admin.

It install perfectly but it give some issue whenever i click on sales channel.

It is not going to show me index page.

it shows this error.

Also shopify review my app and then returns with the following feedback.

Correct your use of App Bridge using our documentation. Your OAuth redirect request fails to escape the iframe and doesn't successfully direct to your embedded app's version. However, your app does successfully use App Bridge from the installed apps list. Make your app's embedded user interface experience consistent to comply with our embedded app requirements. See this screencast for additional details.
[image: See this picture]